# How to solve this error "avrdude: error reading signature data, rc=-67"?

Tags: arduino, avrdude

I am using Arduino Uno WiFi.

At first, the sketches were successfully uploading on the board.

Then, I started getting the following error without changing anything in the code:

[image: error in the image]

Is it a hardware problem, or the board is broken?

Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet from the [avrdude source code](https://github.com/sigmike/avrdude/blob/f3d3c3c126e916e0f5591f18f18d05b35a33bbc2/main.c#L868) that causes the observed error message:

```
/*
   * Let's read the signature bytes to make sure there is at least a
   * chip on the other end that is responding correctly.  A check
   * against 0xffffff / 0x000000 should ensure that the signature bytes
   * are valid.
   */
  if(!(p->flags & AVRPART_AVR32)) {
    if (init_ok) {
      rc = avr_signature(pgm, p);
      if (rc != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: error reading signature data, rc=%d\n",
          progname, rc);
        exitrc = 1;
        goto main_exit;
      }
    }
```

So I guess either you selected the wrong target or the chip is not responding.

Comment: Thank You for your reply  ^__^

Comment: I guess the target is correct cz it was compiling before